# day change has something wrong in wheel datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

In my wheel date picker, A problem occour in 28,29,30 or 31 of month. Now, That problem isn't seen. To check the error,
(1) Please, change the day of your emulator in 31.3.2014 or 30.1.2014.... something like this.
(2) Run the code and you'll see February and some months have something wrong.[Here is the source code](http://sunilsuthar02.blogspot.com/2013/04/date-picker-like-iphone-in-android.html)

Here is my code...

```
Calendar updateDays(WheelView year, WheelView month, WheelView day) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        if(Number == 0){
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,1900+year.getCurrentItem());
        }else{
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,+curYear+year.getCurrentItem());
        }

        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month.getCurrentItem());

        int maxDays = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        //day.setViewAdapter(new DateNumericAdapter(Mcontex, 1, maxDays, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1));
        day.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(Mcontex, 1, maxDays, "%01d Day"));

        int curDay = Math.min(maxDays, day.getCurrentItem() + 1);

        day.setCurrentItem(curDay - 1, true);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, curDay);

        Log.i("curDay",curDay+"");
        Log.i("maxDays",maxDays+"");
        Log.i("Calendar.DayOFMonth",Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+"");

        return calendar;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem... If someone get the same error, this may be the help... :)

```
    Calendar updateDays(WheelView year, WheelView month, WheelView day) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int maxDays = 0 ;

    if(Number == 0){
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,1900+year.getCurrentItem());
    }else{
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,+curYear+year.getCurrentItem());
    }

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month.getCurrentItem());
    int YearChanging= 1900+ year.getCurrentItem();

    switch(month.getCurrentItem()){
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 8:
    case 10: maxDays= 30; break;

    case 0:
    case 2:
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 9:
    case 11: maxDays=31; break;

    case 1:
        if ((YearChanging % 400 == 0) || ((YearChanging % 4 == 0) && (YearChanging % 100 != 0))) {
            maxDays =29 ;
        } else {
            maxDays = 28 ;
        }
        break;
    }

    day.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(Mcontex, 1, maxDays, "%01d Day"));

    int curDay = Math.min(maxDays, day.getCurrentItem() + 1);

    day.setCurrentItem(curDay - 1, true);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, curDay);

    return calendar;
```

}